# Channel Polls : 'Allow users to vote on multiple answers' Conditional?

Tags: devdemon, channel-polls

One of the options in the field setup is to allow users to select more than one answer ('Allow users to vote on multiple answers' Yes/No).

There doesn't seem to be any mention in the docs of a conditional I can use to test this in my templates. Something like `{if poll:multiple_vote}` so I can at least swap out radio buttons for checkboxes.

Is a conditional like this already built in but simply missing from the docs, or do I need to hack the module to get it to work correctly?

Comment: For those looking for a quick fix for this and you only have 1 poll in the channel field group, you can use the {if poll:form_name == 'answer[]'} checkbox {if:else} radio {/if} conditional as 'answer' seems to be the default form element name and the '[]' is appended to it when multiple answers is set in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have added a new conditional to Channel Polls that will be in the next release. If needed now simply email us, though I imagine you are the person we already built this for today!

This conditional is now included in the software.

```
{if poll:multiple_votes}
```

So do checkboxes instead you would do this:

```
{if poll:multiple_votes}
   <ul>
        {poll:answers}
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="{poll:form_name}" value="{poll:form_value}">   {poll:answer}</li>
        {/poll:answers}
  </ul>
{if:else}
   <ul>
        {poll:answers}
            <li><input type="radio" name="{poll:form_name}" value="{poll:form_value}">   {poll:answer}</li>
        {/poll:answers}
  </ul>
{/if}
```